# How to use System Media Transport Controls in Flutter Windows platform

Tags: windows, flutter, media

I wrote a music player using flutter and want to implement System Media Transport Controls function on windows.

How to use System Media Transport Controls in Flutter Windows platform?

Any package or code example?

[image: SMTC etd]